# C# IF one value

Tags: c#, search, if-statement, multiple-instances

This is C# with ScriptHookDotNet.
I saw one time the code, where codder used some instructions to set up one thing and called property to it.
It looks like:

```
if(Player.Character xxxx yyyy in
(
  .IsOnGround == true
  .IsInAir == true
)
)
```

etc.
Someone could me explain what was in "xxx" and in "yyy"? How it is called?

Comment: That isn't C#... not even from afar. Write exactly what you saw.

Comment: Looks like a game object position 3 axis co-ordinates

Comment: You *may* be talking about [LINQ queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) but your current code wouldn't compile.

Comment: This is C#... but using ScriptHookDotNet. And that i just remeber from code. I can't find where I saw it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ScriptHookDotNet` but you should probably edit that into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess it would be

```
foreach(Player.Character xxxx in yyyy.Where(x => x.IsIsOnGround || x.IsInAir))
{
}
```

This would find any player in list `yyyy` where the character is on ground or in the air

Comment: Note: I wrote this before OP said anything about ScriptHookDotNet

Comment: Not sure that addition makes a difference as this is a good guess.

Comment: Mayby that was this. But now i think - this is not better than normal foreach? Also - in my code i can't call "where" [this is List]

Comment: Okey this can work, but i got a list. The list is not a "Ped" type, so mayby that can't allow for me to use "where". I just used many if with ||...

Comment: You need to include system.linq to use this

Comment: Okey so, what is better? Call "foreach in" and then just check with if, or better use "x => x.isonground"?

Comment: That's a debate for the masses, I prefer linq